# How can I write R code for keras to try out different nodes, learning rates, dropouts etc to find optimal model

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, model

I am working with keras and tensorflow in r.

I want my model to learn to classify between 0 and 1 using many measurements, which i input in the first layer.

I have gotten it to work with a "smaller" number of inputs (appr 500.000 input measurements), but cannot get it to work with higher amounts of measurements (>>1.000.000 measurements).

I assume that I have to optimize my model.

**My question is, can I write some code so keras uses different values for 
learning rate, 
decay, 
number of input nodes, 
dropout rate 
one after the other and afterwards presents me with some kind of readout matrix (curves of val_acc for example or accuracy of my test sample), so I can begin to figure out, which parameters might work?**

I have tried using the parameters that work for my smaller model and work up/down from there, but to no avail. Also the smaller model is quite sensitive to changes in all given parameters, so I feel like it would take forever to find good parameters for the large model by hand.

My smaller one looks like this and gives me 75% accuracy in my test, which is already not too bad, but I hoped that more measurements might help me in getting higher accuracy:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 42, input_shape = c(measurements)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(0.9) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')
sgd <- optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.1, decay=0.001)
model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = sgd,
  metrics = 'accuracy')
history <- model %>% fit(
  data.training, data.trainLabels, 
  epochs = 100, batch_size = 64, 
  view_metrics = FALSE,
  callbacks = callback_tensorboard("logs/run_a"),
  validation_split = 0.2)
score <- model %>% evaluate(data.test, data.testLabels, batch_size = 20)
print(score)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after some trial and error.

First, you have to construct data where your values are stored in columns (in my case the columns are "model_units", "model_dropout", "model_lr", and "model_decay").

Then get all possible combinations:

```
require(utils)
parameters <- grid.expand(data$model_units, data$model_dropout, data$model_lr, data$model_decay)
parameters <- na.omit(parameters)
```

Then you can use these in a loop with your model, where you iterate by row.

For this I used doparallel and foreach and had the model use the values from one row as parameters. The model was designated as a function before.

At the end of the loop, I saved the output score$acc (the accuracy of the test set) in the input file in a new column.